# FT_New_Face file path supports non-ASCII characters?

Tags: c++, freetype

I have wstring file path converted to a string that I pass to FT_New_Face and is doesn't work.
Does anyone have such an experience?

Answer (score 0):

Use std::wcstombs. 
[Here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/multibyte/wcstombs) is documentation.